# Is there any way to download my uploaded app in App Store which is under review

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

How can i download the app which i have uploaded to the `ITunes` the app is under review and the chances of app is to be rejected. I have no backup of my app, all files and folder have been deleted. Help to to get rid of this if this is possible.

Comment: If you have used testflight downloading before submitting the app. Try downloading your app from there.

Comment: @SNarula I did not use `testflight`.......i did great mistake.....

Comment: Try it now. Check of you can download the build that you have uploaded

Comment: @SNarula thanx but i tried there is no option!!!

Comment: Downloading the app wouldn't help you anyway; it is just the compiled binary. You need to recover the source files.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanx trying to do that.............

Comment: @Xcodian Try to use Github, bitbucket etc to keep daily backups of your code.

Comment: @SNarula thanx, from now will use Github and bitbucket.............

Answer (score 1):

@Xcodian Sorry but iTunes does not allow the user to download the apps which are under review process, once the app is reviewed or rejected then you can update the app to iTunes.

Comment: but what if my app rejected, then, can is there any possibility to download it?

Comment: I dun think so that iTunes allows downloading the rejected app.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot download and use the build which is under review process. Once you uploaded the ipa to the store, there is no way you can download it even after the app is rejected. The best way is to try recovering the data from your mac. Try some softwares like [this](https://www.cleverfiles.com/recover-deleted-files-mac.html) or [this](https://www.easeus.com/mac/mac-data-recovery-resource/recover-mac-deleted-file-from-trash.htm) or some other softwares. I'm not sure if it recovers all the files, still just try.

Comment: thanx I will try to use this